# how to send files with json object using retrofit2

Tags: node.js, retrofit2

i know this question may have been asked before but it was not working to me.

my code:

```
@Multipart
@PUT("/update")
fun updateClass(
        @Part("data") myData: RequestBody,
        @Part file: MultipartBody.Part? = null
): Call<String>


val imgFile = File(part)

val mFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), imgFile)

val fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", imgFile.name, mFile)

val myData = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), json)

retrofit.create(InterfaceRetrofit::class.java).updateClass(myData, fileToUpload).execute()
```

and here my nodejs console log

```
{ data: '{"id":1,"name":"hhhhhhhhhhh"}' }
{ file:
   { fieldName: 'file',
     originalFilename: 'IMG_20170730_223331.jpg',
     path: 'C:\\Users\\lucius\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\fT-jA8iemxi50AZZG7CM0q2J.jpg',
     headers:
      { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="file"; filename="IMG_20170730_223331.jpg"',
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'content-length': '29388' },
     size: 29388,
     name: 'IMG_20170730_223331.jpg',
     type: 'multipart/form-data' } }
```

is it possible if i want something like:

```
{ data: {"id":1,"name":"hhhhhhhhhhh"} }....
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `JSON.parse` to have your variable converted as a JSON object.

You need to try,

```
JSON.parse(put_your_console_log_variable_here)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i know i can do that in nodejs code.
i just trying to find a solution in case i can't do that :) thanks